# SP13: Copying Workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Is there way to copy workflows (i.e. Publishing Workflows) that have been created in SP Designer?  Shouldn't it be able to function the same way as creating a template of a page and/or list in SP2013.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy list workflow form one site to another, you can use the “Export to Visio” ribbon button and the “Import from Visio” ribbon button in the SharePoint Designer 2013, then you need to post Deployment Work before Publishing.

Here is a great article for you to take a look at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/09/18/how-to-use-the-visual-designer-to-move-workflows-between-sites.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to copy a list workflow without using visio? Thanks